# anybody has some dropdowns datepicker for asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

anybody knows where can I find a html helper or something that is going to generate a datepicker composed from 3 dropdowns ?

Comment: @Omu: Can you be more specific on what you mean by "three dropdowns"?

Comment: I assume a dropdown list for day, month and year?

Comment: yes, separate dropdowns for day/month/year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my little helper.

Itself explanatory, I believe. Can be tweaked to arrange the order of the drop-downs (Month/Day/Year or Day/Month/Year), and if you're using .NET 4, you can put default parameters for the names.

**Edit:** Cleared up the text to reduce eye bleeding

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a days, months, years drop down list using an HTML select control. 
/// The parameters represent the value of the "name" attribute on the select control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dayName">"Name" attribute of the day drop down list.</param>
/// <param name="monthName">"Name" attribute of the month drop down list.</param>
/// <param name="yearName">"Name" attribute of the year drop down list.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string DatePickerDropDowns(this HtmlHelper html, string dayName, string monthName, string yearName)
{
    TagBuilder daysList = new TagBuilder("select");
    TagBuilder monthsList = new TagBuilder("select");
    TagBuilder yearsList = new TagBuilder("select");

    daysList.Attributes.Add("name", dayName);
    monthsList.Attributes.Add("name", monthName);
    yearsList.Attributes.Add("name", yearName);

    StringBuilder days = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder months = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder years = new StringBuilder();

    int beginYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 100;
    int endYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
        days.AppendFormat("<option value='{0}'>{0}</option>", i);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        months.AppendFormat("<option value='{0}'>{0}</option>", i);

    for (int i = beginYear; i <= endYear; i++)
        years.AppendFormat("<option value='{0}'>{0}</option>", i);

    daysList.InnerHtml = days.ToString();
    monthsList.InnerHtml = months.ToString();
    yearsList.InnerHtml = years.ToString();

    return string.Concat(daysList.ToString(), monthsList.ToString(), yearsList.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I guess it requires some javascript for client side constraints, cuz now everybody will be able to select 31 february

Comment: Yeah, just be sure to put the constraint check server side also.

Answer (score -1):

[Telerik has a library](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc) of some ASP.Net MVC controls that is free.

They work as helper methods and look pretty good.  For example, the DatePicker works like this:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
        .Name("DatePicker")
        .MinDate(Model.MinDate.Value)
        .MaxDate(Model.MaxDate.Value)
        .Value(Model.SelectedDate.Value)
        .ShowButton(Model.ShowButton.Value)
%>
```

Comment: no, that's a datepicker with a calendar, I want one composed from 3 dropdowns